Can we send WhatsApp message using Freshchat API without template? Also facing issues to fetch all outbound-messages
I am new to Freshchat (freshworks) portal, I am working on to send outbound messages by WhatsApp to the customer. Without template, can we send outbound messages by API. I am working on .NET technologies. Trying API calls in Postman. I just want to know whether we can send outbound messages without template details?
I have referred API documentaion link of Freshchat, there is showing "template_name", "rich_template_data" field are marked as MANDATORY. Have anyone tried without Freshchat templates for WhatsApp outbound messages?
Correct me, if anyone found that my doubt is irrelevant.
I have tried to get details using API key with URL. Some features are working. While trying to get all messages by the api link
GET : {{URL}}/outbound-messages for above request I am receiving below JSON response.
{ "code": 404, "status": "NOT_FOUND", "message": "request_id is invalid" } . Check below images to get all messages
I could not understand why we need to send request_id to fetch ALL messages.

And also could not find proper fields to send outbound-messages without templates.

Whatsapp outbound message in freshchat cannot be sent without a template.
You will get an error response like this.
data: {
  success: false,
  error_code: 5,
  error_message: 'template_name is required'
}

Anyhow, if you havent added rich_media like image or document in the template while creating it from dashboard, you can omit the rich_template_data and it'll work just fine.
However, if rich_media was added in template, you will have to provide an adequate data in the request to send the message.
Otherwise you will get an error response like this.
{status: 'FAILED', failure_code: '4113', failure_reason: '2008: Template media format is unsupported.'}

This will be the response when you have wrong type in header or wrong media_url extension.
Hope this helps.

Thank you George Thomas, as your answer without template details we could not send outbound messages. I've succeeded by Postman API call with below JSON request to send outbound message.
Request type: POST
Request Url: https://freshchat-url.provided-by-Freshchat-to-send/freshchat.com/v2/outbound-messages/whatsapp
Authorization: Bearer Token "Provided by Freshchat"
Request body: JSON format (check below)
{
"from": {
    "phone_number": "+00000000"
},
"to": [
    {
        "phone_number": "+010203040506"
    }
],
"data": {
    "message_template": {
        "storage": "conversation",
        "namespace": "template_namespace_Guid_provided_by_freshchat",
        "template_name": "template_name_provided_in_freshchat",
        "language": {
            "policy": "deterministic",
            "code": "en"
        },
        "rich_template_data": {
            "button": {
                "subType": "url",
                "params": [
                    {
                        "data": "https://css4.pub/2015/icelandic/dictionary.pdf"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
}

OUTPUT:
 {
"request_id": "received_request_id_from_freshchat",
"request_process_time": "1",
"link": {
    "rel": "outbound-messages",
    "href": "/v2/outbound-messages?request_id=received_request_id_from_freshchat",
    "type": "GET"
},
"status": "Request created successfully. Check delivery status using status API"
}

The "rich_template_data" section content will be differ according to the template parameters.
"rich_template_data": {
            "button": {
                "subType": "url",
                "params": [
                    {
                        "data": "https://css4.pub/2015/icelandic/dictionary.pdf"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

